# Blob does not exist when using BeginUploadFromStream

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

After I use CloudBlob.BeginUploadFromStream() method to upload a file, I later get a StorageClientException with StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound when trying to retrieve the file for a download. If I upload the same file using CloudBlob.UploadFromStream() method, then the blob DOES exist and i can download it.

here's my download code:

```
var client = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = client.GetContainerReference(BLOB_CONTAINER_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS);
container.CreateIfNotExist();

string blobName = id.ToString();

var newBlob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
if (newBlob.Exists())
{
    var stream = newBlob.OpenRead();
    return stream;
}
else
{

    throw new Exception("Blob does not exist!");
}
```

Exists is an extension method. I'm getting the StorageClientException with the error code ResourceNotFound when I use the BeginUploadFromStream() method

```
public static bool Exists(this CloudBlob blob)
{
    try
    {
        blob.FetchAttributes();
        return true;
    }
    catch (StorageClientException e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorCode == StorageErrorCode.ResourceNotFound)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And my call to upload

```
var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
```

This will NOT throw an exception when i later check if the blob exists

```
blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
```

This will

```
AsyncCallback uploadCompleted = new AsyncCallback(OnUploadCompleted);
blob.BeginUploadFromStream(fileStream, uploadCompleted, documentId);
```

**EDIT**

As suggested, i didn't have a call to `EndUploadFromStream()` method. Here is my updated call to upload:

```
blob.BeginUploadFromStream(fileStream, uploadCompleted, blob);
```

And my handler

```
private void OnUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
   var blob = (CloudBlob) result.AsyncState;
   blob.EndUploadFromStream(result);
}
```

Running this, the `EndUploadFromStream()` method throws a `WebException` with the msg: `"The request was aborted: The request was canceled."` The `InnerException` is `"Cannot close stream until all bytes are written."`

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

`BeginUploadFromStream` uploads the blob asynchronously, so your method proceeds while the blob uploads on a thread in the background. If the blob hasn't finished uploading -- or if Azure hasn't been told that the upload has completed -- you won't see the blob in storage. Only blobs uploaded through successfully completed transactions are visible.

Could you post the code for `OnUploadCompleted`?

It looks at first glance as if either the blob is still uploading -- or you've forgotten to call `EndUploadFromStream()` in your `OnUploadCompleted` method.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, i didn't have call to EndUploadFromStream(). Now i've added it and it's throwing an exception. But maybe this is not how to call it? i'm having trouble finding examples of how to use these methods. Question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like is happening is IIS is cancelling the thread that is being initiated to make the BeginUploadFromStream. Since the storage API is really just manipulating a bunch of REST calls under the hood you can think of these storage calls as web service calls and not like traditional IO.

Check out this topic on HttpKeepAlives, this might solve your problem but as the article pointed out it may impact performance of your site. So you may want to add logic to only enable the keep alive for the requests that are performing the upload.

http://www.jaxidian.org/update/2007/05/05/8/